# SQLDataSource FilterExpressions: how get data with just similar values, not equal?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sqldatasource

I have a GridView with the address column, i added a button that calls a filter expression that suppose to look in that column any address, but with this filter expression if the address is not equal the GridView returns blank.

What i need is a filter expression that looks for a word, in that way if the user knows the street or the avenue he can make a correct search.

This is the code with the filter expression called when in the event:

```
 protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression = "Address like '" + TextBox16.Text + "'";
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression = "Address like '%" + TextBox16.Text + "%'";
```